# Move single ip address accross network or virtual machines

Tags: networking, routing, vps, switch, ip-address

I'm currently trying to set up a small development cluster inside our enterprise network. We have a system to provision "disposable" virtual machines and move them to any of our 12 servers if needed. The servers are connected to a cisco L3 switch and we have a /24 assigned to it.

I would like to be able to assign ip addresses individually to virtual machines.

I do not want to set up a vlan for each (physical) server and assign them a smaller subnet. I really want to assign any ip within my /24 to any virtual machine on any phhysical server on the network.

How are VPS providers doing?

I'm looking for technical terms to help my research, how are these "floating" ip addresses called? What technique is used to assign/move them individually?

Comment: You're question doesn't make any sense. How do you assign an ip address to a virtual machine? The same way you do to a physical machine. I don't see how VLAN's or subnets are relevant to this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the documentation of your Hypervisor-Technology? BOTH - Microsoft and VmWare - offer solutions for moving IP-Addresses around even across data center boundaries.

Also a VLAN per VM does not scale - you are limited in the number of VLANs on a trunk.

The key here is knowing your technology and using automation to configure thee VM's automatically. There is no need for VLAN's for example when your router and all other elements are hardocing the IP addresses to the hardcoded MAC addresses (of the virtual machines).

Comment: I didn't mean a vlan per vm, i meant a larger vlan for each physical server, from which vms can  use ips. You confirm my suspicion that i should use a static arp table on the switch, but what about the routing? Should I use the switch as the default gateway for everything? thank you

Comment: Switch as default gatway does not work per definition - you mix up layers. I suggest reading documentation and using the tehcnology you have - unless you use a non-enterprise virtualization technology that is a solved problem.

Comment: I know it doesn't work as a gateway by default. I don't think I am mixing layers, we're talking about ip address addressing and let them communicate with the internet which implies both l2 and l3. I can and know how to configure my switch as a gateway, I'm just wondering if it is the best solution. I am using plain old KVM as the hypervisor.